# How to present a new screen without a UIViewController in Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have not implemented UIViewController because I have already inherited from another class, and it gives the error that present is not a member of this class

```
func shareAppLink() {           
    let name = "http://aijaz.com"
    let items = [name] as [Any]

    let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
    present(ac, animated: true)     
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Error: Use of unresolved identifier 'present'. I want show share menu in my UITableView when cell is selected.

Comment: Where is the `shareAppLink()` getting called from?

Comment: it is called in didSelectRowAt function of UITableView. This is not issue that where it call actually is that how to show share button because in my class present is not part of my class where I m using. How we use present method without UIActivityController.

Comment: From what i am understanding, You have a separate class for your `shareAppLink()` function. and you can calling it from `didSelectRowAt`.  Have you added `import UIKit` at the top `shareAppLink()` function class? And you can try to do `self.present`

Comment: yes I did all and shareAppLink function is in same class. but I have not extend the UIViewController because I have extends another class that is important for my work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use Respoder Chain to get the parent view controller for a view

```
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

And declare your shareAppLink function like

```
func shareAppLink(sender : UIView) {
    let name = "http://aijaz.com"
    let items = [name] as [Any]
    let ac = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: items, applicationActivities: nil)
    sender.parentViewController(ac, animated: true)
}
```

then in didSelectRowAt, you can call it as:

```
self.shareAppLink(sender : cell)
```

Answer (score 1):

`present(_:animated:completion:)` is a method of `UIViewController`, so it must be called on some type of `UIViewController`.

If your class is initially created by a view controller, then you could try passing in a reference using the [delegation pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html):

> Delegation is a simple and powerful pattern in which one object in a
>   program acts on behalf of, or in coordination with, another object.
>   The delegating object keeps a reference to the other object—the
>   delegate—and at the appropriate time sends a message to it. The
>   message informs the delegate of an event that the delegating object is
>   about to handle or has just handled.

If you created a protocol for your custom class something like this:

```
protocol MyClassDelegate {
    func shareAppLink()
}
```

Then you could conform to that protocol in your View Controller and call the method something like this: `delegate.shareAppLink()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to inherit UIViewController subclass or UIViewController class. By doing that an error should be resolved.